# I have imported time but time.sleep() still won't work

Tags: python

```
def start():
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    start1()

def start1():
    print ("This is the spy game.")
    time.sleep(1)
```

When I run my code I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 7, in start
  File "<string>", line 11, in start1
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
```

How can I correct this issue?

Comment: minimal example - remove everything that isn't relevant: `print`, `input`, answer...

Answer (score 5):

You need to import `time` *at the global level*, outside your functions:

```
import time

def start():
    # ...

def start1():
    # ...
```

By importing it inside the `start()` function you made it a *local* name, and `start1` cannot use it. You'd have to import `time` *again* in that function too. Better to import it as a global instead.